# Why anydesk disconnect frequently?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-control, anydesk

I install last version of anydesk in two pc .

When i connect after 5 second disconnected .
I check my internet speed that is ok.
I check my internet connection by `ping 8.8.8.8 -t` command and it is ok.

My anydesk setting:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to:
[AnyDesk FAQ](https://support.anydesk.com/FAQ)

**Unexpected session ends, disconnects, session interrupts after a certain time**

Sessions may end unexpectedly for various reasons. If you encounter interruptions after a specific amount of time into the session, `go to Settings and switch to the Connections tab. Disable direct connections`. You may also set up a listening port in your firewall for AnyDesk in the Security Settings.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same thing for 2 days. After getting complains about internet slow from my family members, I restarted the internet modem and it works perfect.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As written in FAQ:

try adding "/np" at the end of the AnyDesk-ID/Alias you're trying to connect to. e.g. "000111222/np" or "test@ad/np".

https://support.anydesk.com/knowledge/disconnecting-sessions

Comment: How can I change anydesk id?

Comment: The anydesk ID is the id of remote computer you want to connect to