# AnyDesk | The Connection Reset By The Other Desk

Tags: anydesk

During working with anydesk i repeatedly receive an error like :

> **`The Connection Reset By The Other Desk`**

Sometimes with this error my wi-fi connection disconnects.
What is this damn error?
No where on the internet there is such this error.
Is my wi-fi provider admin trying to connect my anydesk as man in the middle by session hijacking?
I am using anydesk to connect my windows server 2016 vps.

Comment: https://support.anydesk.com/knowledge/disconnecting-sessions

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1524283/1482432

Comment: I tried both of your links. Thanks. But this error is different. What is the other desk?

Comment: The other desk is the device you are connecting to. The error may be different, but the fix can be the same.

Comment: Please put it as answer.

Comment: @SilverLight if the answer on another question is the answer to your question then it should be marked as a duplicate, not simply copied here.

Comment: It's entirely possible that you are looking at this the wrong way, that you have an erratic and unreliable wifi connection that is causing your Anydesk connection to drop.

Comment: @Mokubai what is the other question? I checked my questions and this is not duplicate. links in the these comments are my answer.

Comment: @SilverLight both the Anydesk and Superuser links above say "go to Settings and switch to the Connections tab. Disable direct connections". If that is your answer then your question is a duplicate of the second link above.

Comment: @Mokubai I asked it because i was curious about "the other desk". Some people say it means your vps (other side) and some people are saying it means third person. I thought somebody is trying to access my vps during my alive connection. Now i enabled (Not disable) direct connection in both client and server and added port 7070 in both sides. It is working without that error.